# using jQuery to find div that has class which contains this text

Tags: jquery

I am using this to find some info and append elsewhere

```
$(data).find('.two_column_layout').has('b.warning').each(function (index, element)
```

But i need to narrow down my search for specific text that resides in the b.warning area , so for example , i have 50 tables , and need to find all the ones that have b.warning that contains "This" or "This Text" if it needs to match text exactly ?

```
<table class="two_column_layout">
<tbody>
<tr><td><b class="warning">This Text</b></td></tr>
<tbody>
</table>

<table class="two_column_layout">
<tbody>
<tr><td><b class="warning">Not Append Info Here</b></td></tr>
<tbody>
</table>
```

I tried this and didn't work , but when i remove :contains(This) , the script finds all the b.warning again

```
$(data).find('.two_column_layout').has('b.warning:contains(This)').each(function (index, element)
```

Comment: Please give the full HTML code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to include the single quotes. Also include the `:contains` in the `find()`

```
$(data).find('.two_column_layout b.warning:contains(This)')
```

Comment: i found the issue , the orginal html isn't wrapping the text in the b.warning its wrapping it in the td  <td><b class="warning"></b>This Text</td>

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a quote.

```
$(data).find('.report').has('b.warning:contains("Possible")').each(function (index, element)
```